# JSON parse error: Can not construct instance of io.starter.topic.Topic

Tags: java, spring-boot

Im learning Spring Boot and I made a demo but when I POST a request to add a Object it didn't work!

The error message is:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1516897619316,
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "exception": "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException",
    "message": "JSON parse error: Can not construct instance of io.starter.topic.Topic: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of io.starter.topic.Topic: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@1ff3f09a; line: 2, column: 9]",
    "path": "/topics/"
}
```

My Entity:

```
public class Topic {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String author;
    private String desc;

    public Topic(String id, String name, String author, String desc) {

        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.author = author;
        this.desc = desc;
    }
    //getters and setters
```

My controller:

```
public class TopicController {

    @Autowired
    private TopicService topicService;


    @RequestMapping(value = "/topics", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void addTopic(@RequestBody Topic topic) {
        topicService.addTopic(topic);
    }
```

My service:

```
@Service
public class TopicService {
    private List<Topic> topics = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
            new Topic("1", "topic1", "Martin", "T1"),
            new Topic("2", "topic2", "Jessie", "T2")  
            ));



    public void addTopic(Topic topic) {

        topics.add(topic);
    }

}
```

My json:

```
{
    "id": "3",
    "name": "topic3",
    "author": "Jessie3",
    "desc": "T3"
}
```

Please Help !

Answer (score 77):

For deserialisation purposes `Topic` must have a zero-arg constructor.

For example:

```
public class Topic {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String author;
    private String desc;

    // for deserialisation
    public Topic() {}    

    public Topic(String id, String name, String author, String desc) {    
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.author = author;
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    // getters and setters

}
```

This is the default behaviour of the [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) library.

Comment: provide the solution what you did.

Comment: Most of the case, the reason is, there is no default no-argument constructor as stated in this answer.

Comment: In  case of FirstClass having secondClass as a property, this answer is the best, in conjunction with Andreas below. the FirstClass should have a JsonCreator annot on a constructor which takes the second object ( or List<SecondClass>) as a parameter with JsonProperty annot. and the second Class needs to have an empty constructor with getters and setters for all the properties.

Comment: Please don't use this solution, but use the one below. Any design where need to you need a default constructor for de-/serialization I'd consider extremely legacy. Don't compromise good design with well designed constructors, immutability etc.

Comment: I'm using Lombok and I have @NoArgsConstructor added, but still same issue, Strangely happening in prod env and not in qa env, any pointers?

Comment: Why JSON needs the default constractor?

Answer (score 14):

You need to annotate the constructor with [`@JsonCreator`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonCreator.html):

> Marker annotation that can be used to define constructors and factory methods as one to use for instantiating new instances of the associated class.
>
> NOTE: when annotating creator methods (constructors, factory methods), method must either be:
>
> - Single-argument constructor/factory method without [`JsonProperty`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html) annotation for the argument: if so, this is so-called "delegate creator", in which case Jackson first binds JSON into type of the argument, and then calls creator. This is often used in conjunction with [`JsonValue`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonValue.html) (used for serialization).
> - Constructor/factory method where every **argument** is annotated with either [`JsonProperty`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html) or [`JacksonInject`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JacksonInject.html), to indicate name of property to bind to
>
> Also note that all [`JsonProperty`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html) annotations must specify actual name (NOT empty String for "default") unless you use one of extension modules that can detect parameter name; this because default JDK versions before 8 have not been able to store and/or retrieve parameter names from bytecode. But with JDK 8 (or using helper libraries such as Paranamer, or other JVM languages like Scala or Kotlin), specifying name is optional.

Like this:

```
@JsonCreator
public Topic(@JsonProperty("id") String id, @JsonProperty("name") String name,
             @JsonProperty("author") String author, @JsonProperty("desc") String desc) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.author = author;
    this.desc = desc;
}
```